# How to prove the invertibility of a MA series?

Tags: time-series

In moving-average time series, I was told that the condition for a MA series $Y_t=\Theta(B)Z_t$ to be invertible is for all the roots of $\Theta(B)=0$ lying outside the unit circle. However I only found the proof for MA(1). I wonder what is the general proof for higher order $\Theta$.

I understand that being invertible the actual shock $Z_t$ can be recovered from the observed $\{Y_t\}$. This would hypothetically require the existence and convergence of $\Theta^{-1}(B)$ since
$$Z_t=\Theta^{-1}(B)Y_t.$$
However I cannot explicitly get the expression of $\Theta^{-1}$ not to mention deciding the condition of its convergence.

Could anyone help explain this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well sorry I think I put the wrong tag under this question. After some research I decide the following might be a brief proof:

**Proof**:

Let's note the roots of $\Theta(x)$ as $\zeta_1,\zeta_2,\ldots,\zeta_q$. Suppose that the roots are now ordered by their magnitude: $1<|\zeta_1|\le|\zeta_2|\le\ldots\le|\zeta_q|$. Write $|\zeta_1|=1+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0$.

Obviously for any $|z|<1+\epsilon$, $\Theta(z)\neq0$. Hence,
$$
\frac1{\Theta(z)}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}\psi_iz^i
$$
Should be a convergent series.

Now choose $0<\delta<\epsilon$ and plug $z'=1+\delta$ in the above equation:
$$
\frac1{\Theta(1+\delta)}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}\psi_i(1+\delta)^i<\infty;
$$
Therefore $\exists M>0, |\psi_i(1+\delta)^i|<M$, that is, for all $i$,
$$
|\psi_i|<M(1+\delta)^{-i}.
$$
Hence $Z_t=\frac{Y_t}{\Theta(B)}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty}\psi_iY_{t-i}$ converges therefore invertible.